# change value of input text field

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

That's the html for the input field:

```
 <input id="sku_input_field" type="text" name="items[0<?php echo $uniqueSuffix; ?>][sku]" class="input-text" />
```

And the javascript code that I am trying:

```
$('sku_input_field').value = jsonResponse.sku;

document.getElementById("sku_input_field").value = jsonResponse.sku;
```

So, you see, I am trying 2 approaches, and it doesn't work. I use FireBug to check and the response is NOT empty. I can see all the values that I am setting into it. The value of the field though still remains the same as the one I am typing.

It is that I type an id, and when the object with that id is found in the database I return a json response with some values (this happens in PHP). And one of these values, in the json response, is the one I want to set as a new value of the input field.

[image: shot from the browser console check]

The value of the `sku` attribute is what I want to set as value of the input field. As you see, the response is not empty.

Comment: For approach#1 try like `$('#sku_input_field').val(jsonResponse.sku);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be  :

jQuery

```
$('#sku_input_field').val(jsonResponse.sku);
// Provided jsonResponse.sku is not empty
// Also make sure jquery library is added.
```

Pure Javascript :

```
document.getElementById('sku_input_field').value = jsonResponse.sku;
```

p.s : Please check whether you are using same ID for any other element. ID needs to be unique.

Comment: but why OP's 2nd approach `document.getElementById("sku_input_field").value = jsonResponse.sku;` failed?

Comment: The 2nd approach worked. The problem was that I set the `id` attribute of a tag in the wrong file... (it's in Magento framework - stuff are pretty messed up!)